# Auto update user's browser session for a react App

Tags: reactjs, express, react-redux

I have a react app which is running on express server. I do code changes quite frequently and want to have a way so that my code changes get automatically pushed to user's browser.

It is similar to having hot-update in production that automatically updates user's sessions with latest code changes. One way of achieving this would be to invalidate user's browser sessions on every update which can be done using [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: You could poll the server to check some hash and if that hash is different than the current code hash, then show a message to the user, informing them to reload the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is hot module replacement. You can get more information about it in [here](https://hackernoon.com/hot-reload-all-the-things-ec0fed8ab0)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push from the server to the client, you have to use some kind of library for that, for example [socket.io](https://socket.io/) is a popular example.

The basic idea is that the server is triggering an event and signals that to the client via long running socket connections (that normal http would not support), and the client can act on those events appropriatly.